# Prevent WebView from loading specific URLs

Tags: java, android, webview

I am developing a web view app for my company website. In the articles pages, we have links to related products. For example `site.com/product/product` name. How can I disable all the link that starts with `site.com/product/`?
I have searched here and other websites but I could not find a solution.

```
 private class mWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
   /* @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       
    }*/
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       super.onPageFinished(view, url);
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
       super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        

    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
       view.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById(\"footer\"); footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); var header = document.getElementById(\"header_main\"); header.parentNode.removeChild(header); var bread = document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumb breadcrumbs avia-breadcrumbs')[0].style.display='none'");



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` as following:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    if(request.getUrl().toString().contains("site.com/product/")) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow it worked perfectly. thank you so much. i just receive an error for sdk version. changed thw code like this: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
               if (request.getUrl().toString().contains("site.com/product/")) {
                   return true;
               } else {
                   return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
               }
           }
           return true;/// is that ok?works for all android versions?

Comment: Main idea is if your return `true` from the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, then the webview will not load the url. If you return true for build version less than lollipop, then those devices will not load any url. 
If this is your logic, then your code looks fine. It will work.

Comment: Thank you so much.